# Is it possible to define Github actions in the repo that uses them rather than creating a new repository just for it?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'd like to define an action for project, but I'd rather not create an entirely new repository just to host it since it's very specific to the project and small in scope.

Is there any way to define this action within the project that uses it directly rather than referencing an external repository?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to define your action locally by referencing its path relative to the repository root:

```
steps:
 - name: Run Custom Action
    # Use an action (`my-action`) in your repository
    uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
```